# Database dependent autoincrement ID in DDD

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, identity

If we have an existing DB and we want to follow DDD, how to deal with database generated Ids. For example we have to save an aggregate, get its ID and pass it to another aggregate method. It becomes untidy in a domain service and pollutes the service with DB dependencies (like savechanges), espcially with an ORM.

Please let me know if there is a better way. UUID has indexing issue. How to control the ID from the application code and still not have the perf problem of indexing

I have only the GUID approach and the autoincrement approach. Both have their cons.